# Socket.IO - Middleware and scoping: how should I access global IO object from external middleware?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I've split some parts of a Socket.IO application I'm working on into various middleware that perform operations necessary to the application like managing sessions and enforcing access restrictions.

I am currently trying to write another set of middleware functions to handle a list of currently connected sockets intended to be used to kick specific clients from the server, and I find myself in need of the global `io` object within the context of a `socket.on` event callback to broadcast messages to specific rooms via [io.sockets.in('room').emit(...)](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/293).

As far as I know, if you split your socket events out of your main program the way I have there is no tidy way to access the global `io` object in an external file. Merely `require`-ing the Socket.IO module within the external file will not be enough.

I have come up with this workaround to inject the global `io` object and return a function matching [the signature Socket.IO expects from middleware](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#namespace#use%28fn:function%29:namespace) and it appears to work. Still, I worry.

Is there a more elegant solution for my problem? A cleaner alternative, maybe? Have I missed something in the documentation?

And are there any hidden gotchas to the "solution" I've found?

## index.js

```js
// Other required stuff- Express.js, Mongoose, whatever.
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

var Middleware = require('./middleware.js')(io);
io.use(Middleware);

server.listen(port);
```

## middleware.js

```js
module.exports = function(io) {
    return function(socket, next) {
        socket.on('kickUser', function(data) {
            // Do something with the global io object here.
        });
        return next();
    };
};
```

Any advice would be welcome!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *io* object is an instance a socket.io [Server](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#server).

This instance is also available via `socket.server` from within an event handler.

The following two examples are equivalent:

```
module.exports = function(io) {
    return function(socket, next) {
        socket.on('kickUser', function(data) {
            io.emit('userKicked', socket.id);
        });
        return next();
    };
};
```

---

```
module.exports = function() {
    return function(socket, next) {
        socket.on('kickUser', function(data) {
            socket.server.emit('userKicked', socket.id);
        });
        return next();
    };
};
```

Comment: That is absolutely glorious, and I wish I had seen this while poring over Socket.IO's documentation a few months ago. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!